# div doesnt expand as table expands, or div doesnt center when it expand

Tags: css

Hmm this is strange.

It works in IE but not FF.

Please take a looks at: http://www.sumsy.com/temp/test11/test.html (table is 980px initially)
http://www.sumsy.com/temp/test11/test2.html (table expanded to 1200px)

The problem is, after table is expanded, the outer most div (#body-left) is not centered any more in FF. The space on the left remains the same.

I checked with firebug, it looks like the #body-left div width is fixed at 999px, so it didnt expand when table expands.

I can some how fix it by removing the 999px width from #body-left div. But if i do that, the div wont center any more.

I need it to be centered, so I have to specified a width for it?

Any work around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove the `width` property from `#body-left`, and add `display: inline-block`.
- On `body`, add `text-align: center`.
- On `#body-left`, add `text-align: left`.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/okeha5)

If you care about IE7, add to `#body-left`: `*display: inline; zoom: 1`.